# HTML Width scaling unwanted horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css, html, percentage

I am using percentages on the divs in my webpage but I am having a problem where the divs are extending too far and creating an undesirable horizontal scroll bar, I want the divs to expand to 100% of the page and not exceed it. Any help would be greatly appreciated I have looked at the image sizes and messed around with them and now have tried 100% width on each but to no avail.

**So to clarify I want to the page width horizontally to fit the page width but not so that it creates a horizontal scrollbar.**

Below is my HTML and CSS:

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta content="en-gb" http-equiv="Content-Language">
<title>dfgfdgdfg</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
#picturecontainer2 {
    border-style: none;
    float: left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>




<div id="bannerdiv" align="left" title="Banner">
    <img alt="z" height="114" src="Untitled3.jpg" width="100%"></div>
<div id="container">
    <h3 class="auto-style4" id="container">drgrgergergdg</h3>
</div>
<div id="menubar" style="width: 16%; height: 100px;" title="menu" align = "center">
    <ul>
        <li style ="align = center;""><img alt="logo" height="63" src="images/drgrg.gif" width="126"></li>
        <li ><a href="index.html" style="height: 20px;  class="auto-style5">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="general.html">General</a></li>
        <li><a href="map.html">Site map</a></li>
        <li><a href="rules.html">Rules & Procdures</a></li>
        <li><a href="enviro.html" style="height: 20px">Envirommental</a></li>
        <li><a href="energy.html">Energy</a></li>
        <li><a href="it.html">IT</a></li>
        <li><a href="sap.html">SAP</a></li>
        <li><a href="purchasing.html" style="height: 20px; width: 180px;">Purchasing</a></li>
        <li><a href="quality.html">Quality</a></li>
        <li><a href="safety.html">Safety</a></li>
        <li><a href="hr.html">Human resources</a></li>
        <li><a href="prod.html">Production</a></li>
        <li><a href="eng.html">Engineering</a></li>
        <li><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
        <li><a href="tees.html">Teesdock</a></li>
        <li><a href="cmp.html">Company mobile phones</a></li>
        <li><a href="cms.html">Climate Survery Updates</a></li>
        <li><a href="training.html">Training</a></li>
        <li><a href="sports.html">Sports Dome</a></li>
        
        


    </ul>
</div>
<div id="mainpage" class="auto-style1" style="height: 96px; width:   84%; float:right;height:80; color: #000000; font-size: 11pt; left: 0px; top: 176px;"> 
    <font face="Garamond"><font face="Arial" size="4">
    <p><b>SPORTS DOME</b></p>
    <p><span lang="en-gb"><b><font color="#ff0000" face="Arial" size="4">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    Contact Craig Bayliss Ext 3600 for all Dome bookings, events, circuit 
    training, weight training, table tennis etc.</font></b></span></p>
    <p><span lang="en-gb"><font color="#000000" face="Arial"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    Click</b></font><font face="Arial"> on the links below for more information</font></span></p>
    <p>
    </font><font face="Arial">
    <a href="file://cplfs01/dept/sports%20dome/Application%20Forms" style="TEXT-DECORATION: none">
    Application Forms</a></font></p>
    <p><font face="Arial">
    <a href="file://cplfs01/dept/sports%20dome/Rules%20and%20Procedures" style="TEXT-DECORATION: none">
    Rules and Procedures</a> </font></p>
    <p><font face="Arial">
    <a href="file://cplfs01/dept/sports%20dome/Sports%20Dome%20Booking%20Forms" style="TEXT-DECORATION: none">
    Sports Dome Booking Forms</a></font></p>
    </font> 
</div>
<h3 class="auto-style4" id="container1"style = width:100%></h3>
</div>
<br>
<div id="picturecontainer2" style ="float: left;">
<img alt="z" height="114" src="da.png" width="100%"></div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #008852;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 10%;
}

#main
{
height:100%;
weight:100&
}

html, body {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

#picturecontainer1{
    float: left;
}
#mainpage {
    border: thin solid #008852;
    width: 84%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #EDEFEE;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    color: #008852;
}
#menubar

ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
#menubar a:link, #menubar a:visited
{
    border-top-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #EFF1EB;
    width: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #638529;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border: 1px;
    position: fixed;
}
#menubar a:hover, #menubar a:active
{
    background-color: #7A991A;
}
#menubar {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: none;
    font-size: xx-small;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 11px;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: 0%;
}
#bannerdiv 
{
    
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.newStyle1 {
    text-align: left;
}
footer {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #008852;
}
.auto-style1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 11px;
    font-family: Georgia;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
s
#bannerdiv {
    text-align: center;
}
.auto-style4 {
    margin-left: 0px;
    text-align: left;
}
.auto-style5 {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.auto-style8 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: xx-small;
}
.auto-style6 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: xx-small;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.auto-style10 {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.auto-style12 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: xx-small;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style11 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style9 {
    font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium";
    position: fixed;
}
#container1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #008852;
    clear: right;
}

#table {
}
#mainpage a:link, #mainpage a:visited {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#picturecontainer2 {
    border-style: none;
    float: left;
}
#picturecontainer1 {
    border-style: none;
    width: 126px;
    border-right-width: thick;
    border-bottom-width: thick;
    border-left-width: thick;
}
.auto-style20 {
    text-align: center;
}
.auto-style21 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-width: 0px;
    background-color: #EDEFEE;
}
.auto-style19 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: small;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style17 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: x-small;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style15 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: x-small;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.auto-style18 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
#mainpage a:link, #mainpage a:visited {
}
.auto-style23 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11pt;
    a text-decoration: none; 


}
.auto-style14 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
.auto-style15 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.auto-style17 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style18 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
.auto-style19 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: small;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#picturecontainer2 {
    border-style: none;
    float: left;
}
.auto-style20 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style21 {
    font-weight: normal;
}
#picturecontainer2 {
    border-style: none;
    float: left;
}
.auto-style14 {
    text-align: center;
}
.auto-style15 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
#mainpage a:hover a: active {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style25 {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style26 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: x-small;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style27 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: small;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS Overflow;

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

This will hide the horizontal scrollbar

Answer (score 2):

yes, add overflow:hidden in your css
and please dont use inline css and external css, it makes us viewers more hard to read and understand. Always use either one - preferred external css

Answer (score 1):

add:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

to your desired divs CSS

Answer (score 1):

overflow-x: hidden;
you can fixed that error.